# @aws-sdk/client-sns nothing happens when sending sms

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-nodejs

Using `aws-sdk` v2 previously works fine before.
I'm trying to use the v3 now and somehow, I get a good response but sms is never received. I wonder if there's some settings I'm missing here.

Here are the steps I took approach.

1. Created a new policy just to publish sns

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. The user is attached to the policy, then created `access token` + `secret access token` for the user.
3. Created code.

```js
import { PublishCommand, SNSClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-sns';

export const sendSms = async () => {

  try {
    const client = new SNSClient({credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY as string,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string
      }});

    const input = { // PublishInput
      PhoneNumber: "+16045181234",
      Message: "test message", // required
    };
    const command = new PublishCommand(input);
    const response = await client.send(command);

    console.log(new Date());
    console.log(response, 'response ');

    return;
  } catch (e: any) {
      console.log(e, 'SEND SMS');
  }
}
```

4. Getting the response

```js
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '6c3f80ea-3ff2-5c38-bda6-dd6e27661c74',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  MessageId: 'a94988b1-ba63-5f5b-a647-d535a2f78f17'
}
```

But not getting any messages on mobile at all and no error thrown too.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or advices.

Comment: May be helpful: [How do I troubleshoot mobile text message (SMS) failures in Amazon SNS?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/sns-troubleshoot-sms-message-failures)